# WP Query - order posts by meta field first and then order the rest

Tags: wp-query, loop, order, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to order product post type with custom meta field for an expiration date.

I want to show all the expiring products (first being the expiring soon ones). After them, I want to show all the rest of the products that have an empty or missing expiration date after them in alphabetical order.

I have this in `pre_get_post` hook:

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',         
        array(
            'key' => 'expiring_date',
            'value' => date('Ymd'),
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'expiring_date',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'expiring_date',
            'value' => ''
        ),              
    );

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    $query->set('meta_key', 'expiring_date');
    $query->set('orderby', array( 
        'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', 
        'title' => 'ASC' 
    ));
```

The problem is that WordPress always shows the expiring products **after** the products with missing date. Changing the `meta_value_num` to `DESC` puts them at the before them as it should be but they are ordered from latest expiration to soonest.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to name and sort your meta query clauses like this:

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',         
        'foo' => array(
            'key' => 'expiring_date',
            'value' => date('Ymd'),
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
        'bar' => array(
            'key' => 'expiring_date',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ),
        'baz' => array(
            'key' => 'expiring_date',
            'value' => ''
        ),              
    );

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    $query->set('meta_key', 'expiring_date');
    $query->set('orderby', array( 
        'foo' => 'ASC',
        'bar' => 'DESC',
        'baz' => 'ASC',
        'title' => 'DESC' 
    ));
```

More information can be found in this [introduction post](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/).

Comment: Yeah, I tried this it still loads them after the products without expiration date :(